# Unreal Visual Studio 2019 taking forever for tellisense

Tags: unreal-4, visual-studio

I'm using the latest unreal engine and visual studio 2019.  I'm having a problem where intellisense can take way too long.  This usually happens when I have just opened the project inf VS 2019, but not sometimes it happens for apparently no reason.  either way, the intellisense is not very snappy.  Is there a fix for this?

Comment: what is NSightVSE?

Comment: Sorry, when I rechecked that, it doesn't seem related at all - not sure why I though it was. Regarding the Intellisense lag - does it happen w/ any VS project or just Unreal? Also, are you using any plug-ins in VS? In the past, some people have had slow down due to [MS Security Essentials](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/434247/view.html)

Comment: There are some tweaks for this, but I have forgotten them and they didn't change much anyway. You're compiling onto a 2.5 million+ lines of code codebase; Intellisense is going to be slow. As you continue to develop, though, Visual Studio is able to cache some of the intellisense stuff so it goes a bit faster.

Comment: yeah.  It's not so much that it's slow when it is working, its that it may not be working and I have to wait until it catches up, which takes quite a long time.